# how to get 2 data from database in one single cell of a gridview in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview

i want to show 2 data from my sql server database in a single cell of a gridview, i have tried this :

```
<asp:GridView ID="engpodataGV1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="910px"
                            DataKeyNames="PONumber" OnSelectedIndexChanged="engpodataGV1_SelectionChanged">
<Columns>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Complition Time">
     <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" Font-Bold="false" Text='<%# Eval("CompletionTime") + Eval("CompletionTimeFormat") %>'></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
       <ControlStyle Width="100px" />
       <ItemStyle BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
      </asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

my query is that: is this the right way to do this? now i have tested it and i am getting error on `+` what to do?

Comment: go on, test it,it will work

Comment: ok thanks for the encouragement ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need the label, the item template accepts any markup. In particular, it could even be:

```
   <ItemTemplate>
       <%# Eval("CompletionTime") %>&nbsp;<%# Eval("CompletionTimeFormat") %>
   </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: ok but if i want use a label then how should i concatenate? should i use `+` like i did or should i use ur part ?

Comment: ok so that worked perfectly but if i want to use label or textbox then what should i do? bcoz this is not working in label

Comment: How about `<asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("CompletionTime").ToString() + Eval("CompletionTimeFormat").ToString() %>`?

Comment: what error are you getting,please paste it here ,also try Text='<%# Eval("field1").ToString + " - " +  Eval("field2").ToString %>'

Comment: find that sir ... actually have to use 2 Labels instead of 1